# ListView bug and acting different each phone

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

The problem I am having is quite unusual. I am using a custon arrayadapter class for listview.
List items that fit into the screen area appears as normal while those items who require scrolling to get appeared, are either in wrong order or they are just repetition of the items in the top of the list. Moreover, by scrolling up and down, sometimes the order of items changes.

Although when i debug glitching items by clicking them all data is correct.

```
taskList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                TaskEntity temp = (TaskEntity) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(ScreenMain.this, "test : " + temp.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

this error only happening in HTC wildfire Platform 2.3.5 Api Level 10 phone.

But when i test my app on Samsung Galaxy S3 4.1.2 Platform  Api Level 16 phone and everything is just fine.

Why i am getting this error?
is my custom adapter the problem?

```
public class MyTaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TaskEntity> {

    private final List<TaskEntity> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public MyTaskListAdapter(Activity context, List<TaskEntity> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_task_layout, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = objects;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView label;
        protected TextView count;
        protected ImageView icon;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_task_layout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.label.setText(list.get(position).title);

            if(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).tbl_durum)==1)
            {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_icon);
            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).child_count)==0)
            {
                holder.count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.count.setText(list.get(position).child_count);
            }
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_task_layout, null);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    viewHolder.count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
    viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    view.setTag(viewHolder);

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.label.setText(list.get(position).title);

    if(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).tbl_durum)==1)
    {
         holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_icon);
    }
    if(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).child_count)==0)
    {
         holder.count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.count.setText(list.get(position).child_count);
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Basically pass on using the convertView. This causes a lot of those problems.
And if there are not that many object in your list, it would not matter.